# Перемещение нарисованных фигур

Tags: vb.net, .net

Добрый день!
Нарисовал элипс

```
g.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), New Rectangle(e.X - 1, e.Y - 1, 2, 2))
```

Теперь возникла потребность переместить элипс, как это можно реализовать? То есть надо нажать на элипс и начать перемещение движением мышки. Я понимаю, что нужно думать в плане MouseMove, MouseClick. Но как взаимодействовать их вместе? И как определить, какую именно перемещать фигуру.
Благодарю!
Работаю в Visual Basic .NET

Comment: Попробуй нарисовать на панели и её переместить

Comment: А то есть создать Panel динамически,с размерами равные фигуре?

Comment: Насчет этого я незнаю

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо понимать, что ваш Эллипс - это объект, у которого есть свойства. Меняя свойства- изменится объект (положение и т.п.).
Чтобы обратиться к объекту надо иметь на него ссылку, ссылками на объекты (а точнее на их выделенное пространство в памяти) осуществляют переменные.
Вывод - создайте переменную имеющую класс вашей фигуры (в частности эллипс рисуется за счет класса прямоугольника). И дальше вы сможете полноценно управлять вашей фигурой обращаясь через переменную и меняя ее свойства.
А чтобы изменения отобразились необходимо фигуру перерисовать снова и снова - после каждого изменения.

Для большего просвещения прочитайте книгу - Трусов М. А. "Visual Basic .NET. Создание графических объектов и основы программирования"

Answer (score 0):

Просто не большой пример набросал (думаю разберешься):

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim test As New Ball

    Dim Trap As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseUp
        Trap = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseDown
        If e.X > test.MePosition.X And e.X < test.MePosition.X + 100 Then
            If e.Y > test.MePosition.Y And e.Y < test.MePosition.Y + 100 Then
                Trap = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
        If Trap = True Then
            test.SetPosition(e.X - 50, e.Y - 50)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        test.OnDrawed()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 1
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Ball

    Public MePosition As New Position
    Public G As Graphics

    Public Function SetPosition(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
        MePosition.X = X
        MePosition.Y = Y
        OnDrawed()
    End Function

    Sub OnDrawed()
        G = Form1.CreateGraphics
        G.Clear(Color.Blue)
        G.DrawEllipse(New Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), New Rectangle(MePosition.X, MePosition.Y, 100, 100))
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Position

    Public X As Integer = 0
    Public Y As Integer = 0

End Class
```